# Styling Android ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The image will explain everything i need ;)[image]

I'm looking for the exactly same style ( with the thin line also that is near to their logo) (keep in mind i have the logo drawable file )
**UPDATE**
Now i'm getting exactly what i want but i have one bug yet.
[image]

How to remove the arrow highilited in red? keep in mind i'm extending Sliding Menu

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getActionBar().setLogo( R.drawable.logo );

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getActionbar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);` to remove the icon from the actionbar and then `getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)` to enable the arrow but the image you show looks like they created an image with an arrow and replaces the icon with that arrow image.

so in other words you would use this

```
getActionBar().setIcon();
```

Comment: remove the arrow by setting `getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)` to false

Comment: Now the logo i have putted disappear as well

Comment: getSupportActionbar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.menusettings);

Comment: get rid of the `.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false); ` you are removing your image with that